# Bootstrap drowpdown not working when placed in .net masterpage

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have placed a bootstrap navbar in a .net masterpage. This code runs perfectly when on another page without the masterpage, but if on the masterpage, it does not work.

```
    <link href="../plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../plugins/pnotify/css/jquery.pnotify.default.icons.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />

    <script src="../plugins/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.15/jquery.form-validator.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/notify/notify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <!-- Fixed navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XX</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                              <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                              <li class="divider"></li>
                              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Default</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Anyone? About to throw my computer out the window.

/Bob

Comment: It works for me. Are you scripts loading properly?

Comment: Not getting any warnings, and everything else seems to work fine. You just cut n pasted it into a master page? And it worked?

Comment: I don't have *exactly* the same site layout, but the dropdown works in a master page using the Bootstrap CDN. I suspect it's a problem with the paths to the script files, which will be resolved relative to the content page, not the master page.

Comment: Richard, you are right. I changed to CDNs and it worked fine. When I looked more carefully, the script urls are incorrect coming from the MasterPage. Meaning, the MasterPage renders the path as ../js/jquery.js for example, but the master page child needs it to be ../../js/juery.js, for example. Do you know how I can resolve that?

Comment: The simplest option is probably to add a `ScriptManager` to your master page, and use `ScriptReference` to replace your `<script>` tags. That way, you can specify app-relative URLs for your script files.

Answer (score 1):

if you check your browser inspection tool, I think you may be having this error:

```
Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery")
```

Bootstrap.js has a jQuery dependency. So you need to load the jQuery first script before bootstrap.js.

this should be the order. right above the `</body>` tab. The path should be relative to where you have placed your file.
NOTE: use /parent_folder/..path_to_your_files

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope this helps. :-)